# struts2 interceptor redirecting twice to action

Tags: java, redirect, struts2, interceptor

i have a logininterceptor that checks session member object and if it is null redirect it to login page,else continue to action .

Every action blocks has this interceptor. The problem is When you call action it hits the interceptor, if it is true continue to action method, then return "success" or "input" then again hits the interceptor to redirect that selected result name.

How can i prevent to call interceptor twice?

Interceptor code :

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (session.getAttribute("member")==null) {

        return Action.LOGIN;
    } else {
        return actionInvocation.invoke();
    }
}
```

struts.xml action view :

```
    <action name="actionName" class="actionClass" method="init">
        <interceptor-ref name="loginStack"/>
        <result name="input">show.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Comment: not a specific action. Interceptor is simple implements class of com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor

Comment: Can you clarify your concern? Interceptors are typically called twice, that is why it is an interceptor stack.  You drill down the stack call the action and then it returns back up the stack. If you are redirecting then it would be called again... but redirecting is a generally something to be avoided.  The whole process is very fast so it should not matter unless there is something else happening. BTW you can just say: actionInvocation.getInvocationContext().getSession() and remove the second line.

Comment: @Quaternion They're not "called twice", they're called once, and wrap action execution. I don't know why redirection is to be avoided, either; what's the argument for that?

Comment: I should watch my bad language, of course they are call called once.  It was not clear to me why the OP thought they were called twice and perhaps was tracing execution somehow and just watching the call unwind.  I don't know why I said that about the redirect... I don't like redirection at the action level when it aught to be in the interceptor because it looks like he is using xml and that makes for spaghetti xml (well you need to flip between the actions java and the actions xml across multiple actions to figure out what is happening) I could have been completely wrong but I got that...

Comment: ... from the line [The problem is When you call action it hits the interceptor, if it is true continue to action method, then return "success" or "input" then again hits the interceptor to redirect that selected result name.] This to me suggested that the action was doing a redirect if indeed the interceptors were called a second time, and this is what I meant by redirecting should generally be avoided (I think work flow it the responsibility of the interceptors) actions are to marshal data, if two actions share functionality it may be best to show that via inheritance or by pushing...

Comment: functionality up into the service layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *redirect* to a result that has the same interceptor in its refs of course it will be called twice.

If you *forward* to a JSP as you show here, the interceptor will *not* be called again.

---

There's no need to declare this for every action--set the default interceptor stack. For actions that *don't* need this stack (like login) define an interceptor ref for that action that doesn't include this interceptor.